# Sql (mariadb) delete duplicate name and update other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to delete the duplicate name from Table: attribute_lang.
Also, update product_attribute table with id_attribute. 
Please help on sql.

Table : attribute_lang

```
id_attribute,name
1,15
2,16 
3,15 -> remove 
4,16 -> remove
```

Table : product_attribute

```
id_product,id_attribute
12,1
13,2
14,3 -> change id_attribute to 1 
15,4 -> change id_attribute to 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must update your products

```
update product_attribute
set id_attributte = 2
where id_product = 15

update product_attribute
set id_attributte = 1
where id_product = 14
```

After that remove the duplicated

```
delete from attribute_lang
where id_atributte in(3,4)
```